# MVC3 View with multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, view, model

I have a model for a view. This view contains a an @Html.DropDownList whose values are in a model. How can I have my view take both model for different parts of the program?

For example, I have

```
@model IEnumerable<projectname.mymodel>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "my title"
 }
 <!--This should use a different model-->
 <p>@Html.DropDownList(m =>m.name), new set(Model.list, "value", "key"))
```

If I have model1 and model2(connects to database)-all stored in the Model folder; and a big model class as something like

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public model1 var1 { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<projectname.Model.model2> var2 { get; set; }
}
```

And i call this model in my view:

> @model ProjectName.Models.Models

How do I reference an item in model1 or model2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a new class as model to your view which contains all the data you need:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public SelectList list { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<projectname.mymodel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Another approach would be to pass the list in the Viewbag:

```
Viewbag.list = new SelectList() ...
```

Comment: Viewmodel is a much better solution. Don't use the Viewbag for passing models.

Comment: @jpo you have to reference the model like this in your view: `@model MyViewModel`. Then you can use `Model.var1` and `Model.var2` to access the two properties.

Comment: That is what I thought but when I try that, this is the error is get: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.Models.Model1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ProjectName.Models.Model2'. Model1 and Model2 are the two models inside my new class Model

Comment: @jpo then the type your action is returning as model does not match the type you view declares as model type.